# slur or tie to no note in Lillypond

Tags: notation, lilypond, slurs

I am trying to have a slured note to 'nothing' in a musical example in my paper, like this:

[image]

Any tie (~) or slur () I put in Lilypond (actually Frescobaldi), nothing happens.
This is the code I am using:

```
\version "2.18.2"
  global = {
  \key bes \major
  \numericTimeSignature
  \time 6/8
}

violin = \relative c'' {
  \global
  % Music follows here.
  c ees f~
}

\score {
  \new Staff \violin
  \layout { }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That apart - 6/8 doesn't normally group notes like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tie the note to a hidden note.

```
{ \time 6/8 \relative c'' {
  c4 e f~ | \once \hideNotes f c b
} }
```

Comment: You can hide the barline if you want. `c4 e f~ \bar "" \hideNotes f`

Answer (score 5):

Use `\laissezVibrer` instead of `~`.  Cf the [notation manual](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/writing-rhythms#index-laissez-vibrer).